# ROS Simulation for propellers

Tags: ros

I have been trying to simulate a Helium Airship using Gazebo on ROS but can't find plugin to simulate the propellers for thrust. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is liable to be put on hold, as you did not provide any effort in using Gazebo on ROS to simulate the helium airship. It is also too broad as it may require us to program all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to model the propeller like a Quadcopter propeller. See if https://dev.px4.io/en/simulation/gazebo.html helps.